# How to check whether the name of a person got changed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I got a table called Person which consist of ID, Firstname, Lastname, DOD, Create date, Modify date, modify no. Im trying to check whether the name of the person changed during a particular time frame. Here is a sample table. 
I would like to know the people whose first name or last name changed on Jan 2017. Im expecting 1 and 2 in the output. Im using SQL server 2008.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't "4" be selected?

Comment: 4 also should be in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You conveniently have a modify number, which I assume is sequential.  So you can do this with a join and some more logic:

```
select p.*, pprev.firstname, pprev.lastname
from persons p join
     persons pprev
     on pprev.id = pprev.id and
        pprev.modnum = p.modnum - 1
where p.moddate >= '2017-01-01' and
      p.moddate < '2017-02-01' and
      (p.firstname <> pprev.firstname or
       p.lastname <> pprev.lastname
      );
```

If you just want the person ids, then use `select distinct p.id`.

Note:  This assumes that the names are not `NULL`.  The logic requires a bit more comparisons if handling `NULL`s is important.

Comment: select p.*, pprev.firstname, pprev.lastname
from persons p join
     persons pprev
     on p.id = pprev.id and
        pprev.modnum = p.modnum - 1
where p.moddate >= '2017-01-01' and
      p.moddate < '2017-02-01' and
      (p.firstname <> pprev.firstname or
       p.lastname <> pprev.lastname
      );

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself on the ModifyNo

```
select P1.*
from Person P1
left join Person P2
    on P1.ModifyNo = P2.ModifyNo +1
where P1.ModifyDate between @Date1 and @Date2
and (P1.FirstName <> P2.Firstname
     or P1.LastName <> P2.Lastname)
```